# skip carrierwave Integirty and Processing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, carrierwave

I have white listed some of the extensions in the carrierwave uploader class

```
def extension_white_list
    %w(doc docx)
end
```

In some cases I would like to skip the Integrity validation while saving a record. But as per their documentation validates_integrity_of validation exist by default.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-uploads-with-Active-Record

can anyone please tell me how to skip such validation ?

Answer (score 3):

in `uploaders/file_uploader.rb`

```
def extension_white_list
  if model.do_i_need_validation?
    %w(doc docx)
  else
   file.extension
  end
end
```

and define this instance method in the model

```
def do_i_need_validation?
  condition? ? true : false
end
```

Just replace the content of the method suitable to your app

Comment: thnx for ur answer.. but unfortunately it dint work..

Suppose If I try to execute this statement..
    
attachment.avatar= File.open("file.jpeg").. the value of avatar still remains nil

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything about this in any of carrierwave's documentation, but reading its source code, one can pass specific uploader options in the `mount_uploader` call:

```rb
mount_uploader :field, MyUploader, options
```

Validations configuration do exist in uploader options, so you can, for example, disable all validations using:

```rb
mount_uploader :field, MyUploader, validate_download: false, validate_integrity: false, validate_processing: false
```

Note that when doing this the errors are silently ignored, so saves will succeed. This could be unexpected behavior. You can check if the operation actually had any errors using the model helpers `<field>_processing_error`, `<field>_integrity_error` and `<field>_download_error`:

```rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader, validate_integrity: false
end

article = Article.find(1)
article.update_attributes!(title: "New article title", image: open("/path/to/invalid_image.jpg")) # => this will actually succeed
article.image_integrity_error # => returns the error message from carrierwave
```