# Use two different validations at extension_whitelist method of Uploader CarrierWave model is nil before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I have a problem with the validation "extension_whitelist" at CarrierWave Uploader. The `model.is_special_category?` return nil, any other way to validate it?
I want to allow only image if the category is "special category"
uploader:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    def extension_whitelist
        return %w(jpg jpeg gif png bmp svg ) if model.is_special_category?
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png bmp svg pdf docx doc xlsx xls odt ods csv )
      end
end
```

model:

```
class AttachedFile < ApplicationRecord

  def is_special_category?
    category == 'Special Category'
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post `is_exhibit_picture?` method (you posted `is_special_category?`).

Comment: I don't know if is good Idea remove the `extension_whitelist` at the FileUploader and create a custom method to validate the format at the model with `validates_format_of :url, :with => regularExpresion` what do you think?

Comment: I will stick with `extension_whitelist`, there is no need to roll my own validation if CarrierWave already handles it. Is there any particular reason for this change?

Comment: Yes I had the same idea, but when I tried to validate the category into the `extension_whitelist` it always return `nil` I try to with it `model.category` I saw some other similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233816/skip-carrierwave-integirty-and-processing-validation) that I tried to resolve it.